# Hudson with MSBuild and MSTest, how to get code coverage

Tags: msbuild, hudson, mstest, code-coverage

Do you have some opinion for code coverage in Hudson.. Now i have build with Msbuild and MSTest and that's work.

But for code coverage, i think i need some help. I have searched that somebody use nCover another with Emma. Which one is better and more easier ? And maybe reference to help me.

Best regard,

Answer (score 0):

Are you .NET (NCover) or Java (Emma) or both?

NCover should work with Hudson but costs

Open Source projects exist look for [PartCover](https://github.com/sawilde/partcover.net4) and more recently [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover).

All three .NET tools support command-line and as such they should integrate with Hudson.

Answer (score 0):

We are currently using dotCover by JetBrains.  It's cheaper than NCover and it integrates well with Visual Studio.  You don't have to use a separate application (NCover Explorer) to view your code with the covered/uncovered highlighting, which is great.

The command line version of dotCover allows you to create XML files of the analysis and you can parse the XML via <XmlRead> (in the MSBuild Community Tasks library) to parse the output.

It takes a while to get set up properly, but it works.